# Xamarin and autolayout without Interface Builder

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, autolayout

Ok i saw the other question where they suggested to use FluentLayouts but i'd like to do this without it using only the constraint.
So the problems are this:
I have created this app with a navigationBar and a tabBar, now i'm trying to insert in a `MyViewController` 2 buttons, one of them on the middle(the code that i posted) and the right under the navigationBar.

```
//------Appdelegate.cs
   myViewController = new MyViewController ();
   UINavigationController myNavController = new UINavigationController (myViewController);
   window.RootViewController = myNavController;
//-----MyViewController
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            button1.SetTitle("Button1", UIControlState.Normal);
            button1.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            button2.SetTitle("Button2", UIControlState.Normal);
            button2.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
            View.AddSubview (button1);
            View.AddSubview (button2);
            View.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (button1, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View,NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0));
            View.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (button1, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View,NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, 0));
}
```

With this code the button1 is not appearing at all because it is positioned at (0,0) and i don't know why, can someone give me a hint? and the other problem is that i don't know how to get the bottow value of the navigationbar, so i can put button2 there.I followed [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Code) article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
 button1.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
 button2.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

So you can use your constraints, otherwise they will be overwritten by autoresizingmask.
Also you should NOT use

```
EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
```

i think that the wrong position of your buttons is given for this last line

Comment: Yeah i founded out about the AutoresizingMask, but the problem was that there was no button at all with that, with EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None; all the problem solved.. Thanks